# spring контроллер не обрабатывает dto которые содержит map

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

DTO:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CarServiceDTO extends BaseDTO {

  private String address;
  private Map<SparePartDTO, Integer> sparePartsCount;
  private List<MasterDTO> masters = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Когда делаю POST на контроллер , спринг возвращает :

```
{
  "timestamp": 1519151541662,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
  "path": "/CarService"
}
```

Если убрать Map из DTO всё отрабатывает нормально!

Comment: А каким образом Вы храните `Map<SparePartDTO, Integer>` в json`е? Это вообще возможно?

Comment: Так я и не храню, не получается вроде как) , и что делать с этим ? Создавать список с кастомным классом KeyValue?

Comment: Для каких целей Map где DTO ключ? Почему не заменить его на List?

Comment: Есть абстрактный магазин запчастей, ключ - запчасть , значение - их количество

Comment: Сделайте количество полем и запихните в List

Comment: Может запчасть должна быть String?

Comment: А можете объяснить почему я не могу хранить Map в json , json сам по себе вроде как key:Value

Comment: приведите пример отправляемого jsona

Comment: {address:"string"} - если есть Map не работает , без Map в DTO , всё ок

Comment: @flagmen, в json ключ всегда строка